# Null check nested lambda

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently using a lambda to set a property.

```
Team = department.Teams
                 .Where( t => t.GUID == a.Personnel.Roles
                        .Where(r=>r.Department==department && r.EndDate==null)
                        .SingleOrDefault()
                        .DeptTeamGUID)
                 .FirstOrDefault().Name
```

Department has a bunch of teams. A personnel has a role that is connected to that team. The PersonnelRole contains data about the department and which team the role is a part of.

However sometimes a personnel can have a role with no team. In this case I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.

I have also tried to modify the lambda to filter out Roles that doesn't have a DeptTeamGUID, but my logic seems off.

```
Team = department.Teams
                 .Where( t => t.GUID==a.Personnel.Roles
                         .Where( r => r.Department==department && r.EndDate==null 
                                      && r.DeptTeamGUID !=null)
                         .SingleOrDefault().DeptTeamGUID)
                 .FirstOrDefault().Name
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the null-reference exception because you are trying to read a property from a null-reference, when you are doing it using the construct `.SingleOrDefault().PropertyName`.

You have to change `.SingleOrDefault().PropertyName` to `.Select(x => x.PropertyName).SingleOrDefault()`, like this:

```
Team = department.Teams
    .Where(t => t.GUID == a.Personnel.Roles
        .Where(r => r.Department == department && r.EndDate == null)
        .Select(x => x.DeptTeamGUID)
        .SingleOrDefault()
    )
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: this should make it work, but since `t.Guid == null` is not `true`, your case of personnel with no team will not be returned by the query.

Another note: I suspect that you might miss some results that you would normally expect, since you are using the `.SingleOrDefault()` in your subquery. Perhaps you should use `.Contains(...)` to check all guid's. Like this:

```
Team = department.Teams
    .Where(t => a.Personnel.Roles
        .Where(r => r.Department == department && r.EndDate == null)
        .Select(x => x.DeptTeamGUID)
        .Contains(t.GUID)
    )
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```